# Twilio Call routing

Tags: twilio

When a user fills out a form and submits it, I want to trigger a call to the number they provided and after they answer route the call to dial another number for example to customer support representative. So instead of the user dialing the number, I want to make it easier for them and call them instead and then connect them with customer support. What is the best way to implement this using twilio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is a feature we call "click to call". We actually recommend that the flow is the other way around, that you dial your customer support rep first, then they will be waiting on the phone when your customer answers.

We actually have a full in depth tutorial on building a click to call system including example code. I don't know what language you're building in, but your previous SO activity suggests maybe Ruby? So, check out the [Click to Call in Ruby on Rails tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/call-tracking/ruby/rails). If I'm wrong then just check out the [tutorials section](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials?filter-product=voice) and pick your favourite language.

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: I was able to implement what I had in mind earlier - user fills out a form and then they receive call from twilio app which then connects them to another service which has  IVR & call tracking already before connecting them to the service rep. So the problem is, when the other application sees the same number calling, it routes it to the same customer rep center instead of the corresponding state and marks it as duplicate. Is there a way for the twilio to show the user's number instead of the twilio number when it calls out to the customer rep center to be routed to the correct center?

Comment: You can set the `callerId` in the `<Dial>` TwiML to the number you dialled according to the docs here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-caller-id

Comment: In this case, the number you dialled originally is the user, you can then use their number as the callerId when connecting onto the call centre.